# Is it possible to show that the union of a sequence of random graphs is connected when each graph may not be connected?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Consider a sequence of Erdos-Renyi random graphs $\mathcal{G}(1),\mathcal{G}(2),\ldots,\mathcal{G}(T)$ where each one is described by a fixed set of $n$ vertices and the probability  $p$.  We assume that each graph is not necessarily connected.
Is it possible to show  the union of a sequence of random graphs is connected after $T$ samples? What would be  the relationship between p,n, and T?

Answer (score 3):

The union of $T$ ER graphs on the same set of vertices is itself an ER graph, where the edge probability (i.e., the probability that $x$ and $y$ form an edge) is $p$ where is

$1 -\prod_{j=1}^T (1-p_j)$ where $p_j$ is the probability of $\{x,y\}$ forming an edge in the $j$-th ER graph.

With the above noted, I believe a graph $G$ drawn according to ER$(n,p)$ (for $n$ large) is connected for $p \geq \frac{\theta(\log n)}{n}$, and for each $p_1,\ldots, p_T$, the quantity  $1 -\prod_{j=1}^T (1-p_j)$ is at least $\min \{\frac{\log^2 n}{n}, \frac{3 \sum_j p_j}{4} \}$.

Comment: In both the question and your answer, it's important to add the qualifier "with high probability" or if you prefer "asymptotically almost surely": the graph $G$ is not necessarily connected when $p \gg \frac{\log n}{n}$, but the probability that it is connected tends to $1$.

Comment: Of course, "whp" should be in there yes. Indeed a graph drawn according to ER$(n,\frac{1}{2})$ will have no edges with probability at least $2^{-n^2}$.